# SQL: Is there a way to filter and form another column based on data specifics from another?

Tags: sql, database, databricks

I have a list of data, let's say ice-cream flavours and sweets (column A) and I wish to create column B based on specific flavours out of column A:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| chocolate ice-cream | chocolate |
| chocolate cake | chocolate |
| strawberry pie | strawberry |
| fruit cake | fruit |
| strawberry cookie | strawberry |
| fruit cake | fruit |

Honestly saying I'm not even sure where to start, cause it would be easier for me to use filters in GSheets, but I need to automate this process for same tasks going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have a list of possible kinds of sweets [ice-cream, cake, pie, cookie], and column A consists of words for sweets and flavours, then you can write the query using [SPLIT()](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/split.html), [ARRAY_EXCEPT()](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/array_except.html),[ARRAY_INTERSECT()](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/array_intersect.html) and [ARRAY_JOIN()](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/array_join.html) function as below:

```
WITH tableA_w_words AS (
    SELECT
    columnA,
    ARRAY_INTERSECT(SPLIT(columnA,' '), ARRAY('ice-cream', 'cake', 'pie', 'cookie')) as sweet_words,
    ARRAY_EXCEPT(SPLIT(columnA,' '), ARRAY('ice-cream', 'cake', 'pie', 'cookie')) as non_sweet_words
    FROM
    tableA
)
SELECT
   columnA,
   CASE 
       WHEN size(sweet_words)> 0 AND SIZE(non_sweet_words)>0 
       THEN array_join(non_sweet_words,' ') 
       ELSE NULL 
   END AS flavour
FROM
   tableA_w_words
```

Comment: What if it's not the first and there can be undefined amount of words in a cell?

Comment: Hi @Dan, if we have a list of pre-defined words for flavours, we can rewrite the query to fetch those pre-defined flavours. If we don't even have a list of pre-defined words, then it's a NLP(natural language processing) problem which needs ML tools instead of SQL to solve.

Comment: Hi Junjie, thanks a lot for your help. I think it's possible to identify most of the words there. Let's say I can name 90% of the sweets that can be combined with flavours. Then I can keep filtering the results based on what other sweets left once I fetch those 90%. Well, not the best automation, but still.
In other words, as soon as I can extract that 90 percent it's already good to go. If you now the way to do so, use cake, ice-creaming as an example of 90% words we are aware of.

Comment: Hi @Dan, I have updated the query based on the assumption that we know a list of sweets and the columnA consists of sweet and flavour words.

Comment: Hi @Junjie, I've tried your code and here what I got. 
column flavour is filled with the next word that comes after keywords we have in array. But if there were also words after it doesn't add them
So if we have
cookie with chocolate I will only get with, but not cookie.
I would like to get at least "with chocolate" in a result flavour column

Comment: Hi @Dan, I further updated the code to use array_join to merge the non-sweet-words instead of just picking the first one. that should cover the case you describe.

Comment: Hi @junjie, that works good for me. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Hi @Junjie, I have another issue to ask you about. How can I clean up all symbols like ',' '/' etc? Cause they merged to a word